# Publishing MVC6 to IIS 8.5 virtual directory

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Using MVC6 beta5, I've published my web app to \inetpub\myapp, and added an app to my base web site pointing at myapp\wwwroot. When I do so, _layout.cshtml's asp-src-include lines aren't being compiled and all the content goes missing, e.g.:

```
    <script asp-src-include="~/lib/jquery/**/*.js"></script>
```

Everything else works: IIS Express, self-hosting, creating a new web site, so yes I have workarounds. Does anyone have any insight why a virtual directory trips up IIS?